# How to calculate mean of specific rows based on value and column in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm loading in a file to a pandas dataframe that looks something like:

```
A    3    2    4    1
B    1    3    5    2
C    2    8    9    1
A    4    1    2    3
```

I converted the dataframe to a numpy matrix because I'd like to store each mean and variance in separate 26 x 4 numpy matrices that will hold the variance and mean for each feature of each letter. My question is how to do I find the mean and variance for a specific letter and specific column? Also is there a better way to do this than going from the dataframe to matrix or is this an ok way to go about it?

Output I'd be expecting for A would be 3.5 for column one, 1.5 for column 2, 3 for column 3 and 2 for column 4. I would append each of these to a numpy matrix. Eventually the matrix I'd like to generate would look something like:

```
[[3.5, 1.5, 3, 2]
 [1, 3, 5, 2]
 [2, 8, 9, 1]]
```

So the first array are the means of letter A column 1-4, the next array are the means of letter B column 1-4, then letter C columns 1-4. For my actual dataset this would include all 26 letters.

Edit: Honest question, why am I getting downvotes for this? I googled this question and couldn't find any specific answers.

Comment: how is using `np.mean(axis=...)` a problem?

Comment: That won't give me the mean of the specific letter right? I need the mean for column 1 for letter 'A', then the mean for column 1 for letter 'B', etc. until I have the means for each letter and every column. So in total I'd have 112 means.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it but you’ll need to specify column headers and keep your data in a dataframe.

```
 df[column_name].iloc[row_index].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried this and I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm not being very clear in my initial post. I have a dataset of around 15,000 rows. The first column has some letter A through Z. I need the mean for each column of each specific letter. So in total with 4 features I'd need 112 total means, 26 means for each column.

Comment: Can you update your question and show an example of the output you’re looking for? What you’ve asked for and what you want seem to be different.

Comment: I just added the output. My question is more specific to how to calculate the means, not necessarily add them to my matrix but I think my edit should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. I also got my code to work using the dataframe but I'd still like to know how to do it with a numpy matrix.